# Video.js thin black line

Tags: css, html5-video

I'm using the great video.js library to create a custom HTML5 video player for my site. Unfortunately, a thin black line is appearing on the right of the player in Safari. Sometimes, resizing the browser solves the problem, but I think this is a bug.

Here's the LESS that I changed to skin the player (according to http://designer.videojs.com):

```
@base-font-size: 10px;
@touch-device-font-size: 15px;

// The main font color controls the color of the text and the icons (font icons)
@main-font-color: #CCCCCC; // e.g. rgb(255, 255, 255) or #ffffff

// The default color of control backgrounds is mostly black but with a little
// bit of blue so it can still be seen on all black video frames, which are
// common.
@control-bg-color: #07141E; // e.g. rgb(255, 255, 255) or #ffffff
@control-bg-alpha: 0.7; // 1.0 = 100% opacity, 0.0 = 0% opacity

// The slider bar color is used for the progress bar and the volume bar
@slider-bar-color: #1A6DBA; // e.g. rgb(255, 255, 255) or #ffffff
// The background of the progress bar and volume bar have a lined pattern that
// is created from a base64 encoded image. You can generate your own pattern at
// http://www.patternify.com/ then replace the value in the quotes with your own
@slider-bar-pattern: ~'';
// The color of the slider background
@slider-background-color: #333333;
@slider-background-alpha: 0.9; // 1.0 = 100% opacity, 0.0 = 0% opacity

// The "Big Play Button" is the play button that shows before the video plays.
// To center it set the align values to center and middle. The typical location
// of the button is the center, but there is trend towards moving it to a corner
// where it gets out of the way of valuable content in the poster image.
@big-play-align: center; // left, center, or right
@big-play-vertical-align: middle; // top, middle, or bottom
// The button colors match the control colors by default but you can customize
// them by replace the variables (@control-bg-color) with your own color values.
@big-play-bg-color: @control-bg-color;
@big-play-bg-alpha: @control-bg-alpha;
// The font size is what makes the big play button, big. All width/height values
// use ems, which are a multiple of the font size.
// If the @base-font-size is 10px, then 3em equals 30px.
@big-play-font-size: 3em;
// Now that font size is set, the following em values will be a multiple of the
// new font size. If @big-play-font-size is 3em (30px), then setting the any of
// the following values to 2em would equal 60px. 2 * font-size
@big-play-margin: 0.5em;
@big-play-width: 3em;
@big-play-height: 2em;
@big-play-border-radius: 0.5em;
@big-play-border-width: 0;
@big-play-border-color: #3b4249;
```

I don't know why this is happening. Could it be an issue with the video?

Link to the site with issue: http://bluecocoa.com/posts/spaceship-canopy/

Screenshot of issue:
[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort out the issue. The video I was using had an aspect ratio that didn't exactly fit the player. I adjusted the `padding-top` of `.video-js` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the aspect ratio of the video player doesn't perfectly match the actual video's aspect ratio, which results in padding at the borders. A workaround is to change the background color of the video like so:

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
  background-color: white;
}
```